# WordPress Error : Upload folder is not writable. Export and file upload features will not be functional

Tags: php, wordpress

I just migrated my Wordpress data to new server. After that I am unable to upload any media file.

On dashboard error showing "Upload folder is not writable. Export and file upload features will not be functional."

[image: My Dashboard Error, I have also changed my permission of uploads folder.]

Comment: I'm willing to bet that safe mode is enabled on the server you've just migrated to.

Answer (score 15):

I just had this problem after moving the site to a new server.

The filesystem paths on the new server are different to the old server and so your uploads path appears to be un-writable because *it doesn't exists on the new server*.

The problem is that *sometimes* WordPress will populate an option called `upload_path` in the `wp_options` table. Much like the comment above with the PHP Define: `'UPLOADS'` that might be set in your `wp-config.php` this is not ideal as it hard-codes your paths.

So the fix is quite simple, you need to **clear** (as in delete) either the key from the `wp_options` table, or just the value of that key.

How to do that? There's a neat way inside WordPress itself to do this:
(caution: take care not to modify any other field in the following steps other than the one you're looking for).

1. Log into your WP Admin
2. Go to this URL on your site: `/wp-admin/options.php`. This will present you with the full list of WP Options in your `wp_options` database table.
3. Find (Ctrl+F) the following option name: `upload_path`
4. If it's got a value, simply delete what's in that field.
5. Don't change anything else and click `Save Changes` at the bottom

WordPress will then start using the default path (`/wp-content/uploads/`) to your uploads folder

Answer (score 6):

You need to update the permissions of the upload directory.

if you have ssh access something like `chmod a+w wp-content/uploads` or if you're using some FTP client, try right click on the folder and set `group` or `all` write permission.

If you don't know your where your uploads folder is you can check in `wp-config.php` for this line `define( 'UPLOADS', YOUR UPLOAD FOLDER HERE);`

Comment: I've updated so many times with different amount. Can you tell me the exact amount and folder. I tried to make change UPLOADS, 2014/09 & index.php folder

Comment: You probably have the default `wp-content/uploads/`, but you can verify by checking in `wp-config.php` for something like `define( 'UPLOADS', YOUR UPLOAD FOLDER HERE);`.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your environment. Find out what user is running wordpress and run the following:

```
chown -R user:group /root/of/install/wp-content/uploads
chmod -R 755 /root/of/install/wp-content/uploads
```

replace 'user' with the user that wp runs as and do the same for 'group' 
also, make sure the ftp application you use runs as the same user as 'user' above

if you don't care about security, you could just run

```
chmod -R 777 /root/of/install/wp-content/uploads
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The uploads folder was not writable. The uploads path had to be deleted in the database > wp_options table.

Comment: you may wish to make this answer a bit more detailed to clarify how you are suggesting the Paras ought to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by doing following:

1. Open myphpadmin through your cpanel and open your database.
2. Select option table
3. Find row of named as upload_url and click edit
4. Delete the value and hit save